# Karma run with ng test does not find any tests to run

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine, config, karma-runner

So I have the default and one custom spec.ts file laying around in my Angular 10 project and none of them get detected by Karma to run. Any clue why this could be happening?

My Karma Config file (actually unchanged):

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/korrespo-portal'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

My console output:

```
Chrome 88.0.4324.104 (Windows 10): Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS (0.013 secs / 0 secs)
TOTAL: 0 SUCCESS
```

In the Karma UI this gets shown:

```
Incomplete: No specs found, , randomized with seed 27463
```

My `ng version` output:

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 10.1.7
Node: 12.13.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 10.2.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, localize, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1002.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.1002.0
@angular-devkit/core               10.2.0
@angular-devkit/schematics         10.1.7
@angular/cdk                       10.2.5
@angular/cli                       10.1.7
@angular/material                  10.2.5
@angular/material-moment-adapter   10.2.5
@schematics/angular                10.1.7
@schematics/update                 0.1001.7
rxjs                               6.6.3
typescript                         3.9.7
```

I'm running Angular 10 as you can see above and TypeScript 3.9.7 as also shown above...

Answer (score 1):

There should be a file called `test.ts` that has a line like so:

```
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

Those are the lines responsible for finding the tests. Maybe your tests aren't located in `./`.

Comment: The files were located in ./ but I tried autoWatch to false and true again and suddenly it worked again... Strange...

Comment: Having the same problem. Angular docs say to add spec.ts files next to the components/services they are testing which is not always in the root... so I'm confused.. what am I missing?>

Comment: It is related to the context in `test.ts`, I am thinking it's not finding your test files especially if they are not in the root.

Comment: Issue still persists... I already had this in `test.ts`